# Computing $\mathrm{Fix}(\phi)$ for autormophisms $\phi$ of free groups

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, automorphism-group, free-groups

Let $F_A$ be the free group generated by the finite set $A$ and let $\phi\colon F_A \to F_A$ be a group-automorphism. It is known [1] that
$$ \mathrm{Fix}(\phi) = \{g \in F_A : \phi(g) = g\} $$
is (freely) finitely generated. Moreover, if $\phi$ is *positive*, that is, if $\phi(a)$ is a product of the generators for all $a \in A$, then there is an algorithm for computing $\mathrm{Fix}(\phi)$ [2]. My question is whether someone knows an implementation of this algorithm. I tried the usual sources (SageMath, Mathematica) without success. Even if there is an implementation that works for particular cases, it'd be useful for me.

[1] D. Coope. Automorphisms of Free Groups Have Finitely Generated Fixed Point Sets, 1987.

[2] M. Marshall & M. Lustig. On the dynamics and the fixed subgroup of a free group automorphism.

Comment: There are actually algorithms to compute $\operatorname{Fix}(\phi)$ for *any* $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(F_A)$ or even for $\phi \in \operatorname{End}(F_A)$, see [this preprint](https://mutanguha.com/pdfs/relimmalgo.pdf) by Mutahunga (and the references therein). I'm not aware of any implementations, however. The closest might be [this SageMath package](https://www.i2m.univ-amu.fr/perso/thierry.coulbois/train-track/), which implements many of the things used in the aforementioned algorithms. It lists "Fixed subgroup of an automorphism" under "Possible mathematic extensions".

Comment: @sTertooy Thanks! There are several other things that are useful for me in that link.